# How to delete all data from Ember Data store?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

In the Ember.js application I'm working on, that uses Ember-data, once the user gets to a point on the screen, I want to delete all state stored in the ember-data Store associated with the application, and start with a clean slate that can start pulling data from the server. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way. The only way ATM is loop over all your `DS.Model` classes and destroy the records individually.

```
App.Model.all().forEach(model) ->
  model.destroy();

App.Model2.all().forEach(model) ->
  model.destroy()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was seeing in the code for ember-data, just wasn't sure if maybe there was something I was missing.